# How to create xcode project for iPhone Light version app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment

What is the recommended way to create a Light version of iPhone App?

I have an x-code project of my iPhone app which I want to charge money for it. In addition to that app, I would like to deploy additional "light" version of this app free of charge which of course will have some limitations.

Best way I can think of is adding a new 'Light' configuration in my existing xcode project and define a constant like LIGHT_VERSION only in this configuration that will be tested in my code.

Will that solution work? or do I have to create a new 'Light' project pointing to all sources and resources of original project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I manage building a Lite vs Paid version of an iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549462/how-do-i-manage-building-a-lite-vs-paid-version-of-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1):

YES you can define a preprocessor macro LIGHT_VERSION. Use it with

```
#ifdef LIGHT_VERSION
#endif
```

an so to disable/enable features.
For more information please look at: [stackoverflow - xcodebuild - how to define preprocessor macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708380/xcodebuild-how-to-define-preprocessor-macro)

Comment: So I guess I can also provide a different application name and different App ID to this configuration, right?