# Passing compiler flags through xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm currently using `xcodebuild` to automate testing for iOS.

Right now, I'm stuck on trying to pass compiler flags through Xcode directly to the compiler. These flags are: `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`.

I don't have the liberty of modifying the xcodeproj, that's why I want to inject these flags via the xcodebuild command.

It would be something like:

```
xcodebuild -project path/to/my.xcodeproj -scheme MyApp -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
```

Is that feasible? How?

Comment: Try setting them using the OTHER_CFLAGS argument

Comment: The OTHER_CFLAGS argument is already used in the xcodeproj settings sadly :( But I got a solution :) Look below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently most compiler flags can be expressed as constants, and these can be passed to the compiler via xcodebuild easily.

To get them, simply select the option in the xcode build settings view, and hit command-C (copy). In my case, they were `GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES` and `GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS`.

My command roughly looks like this:

```
xcodebuild GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=YES ...
```

Comment: Beware, this answer could lead to confusion. You are not really passing compiler flags here, only overriding the value of some Xcode environment flags, which in turn set the corresponding compiler flags. If you wanted to set some custom compiler flag instead then you'd need to override the OTHER_CFLAGS env var.

Answer (score 6):

To set compiler flags with `xcodebuild`, you need to put them in the `OTHER_CFLAGS` option.

For example:

```
xcodebuild -project path/to/my.xcodeproj -scheme MyApp \
    OTHER_CFLAGS="-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
```

Be aware that this will override any OTHER_CFLAGS set by the project.

Comment: this should be `OTHER_CFLAGS`, not `OTHERCFLAGS`. also it should be noted that if this is already has a value in the project, the previous value will be blown away.

Comment: `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` yields `OTHER_CFLAGS =  -fvisibility=hidden`.  Testing would need to be done to determine if the existing flag is overwritten or appended to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all of the compiler setting actually boils down to string key-value pairs.  I answered a very similar question about setting preprocessor macros from the command line that is just as applicable to these settings you would like to set:

[Setting a #define from the command line in xcode 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708831/setting-a-define-from-the-command-line-in-xcode-4-6/16274290#16274290)

I would also like to call attention to the use of ${inherited} -- using this values allows you to use the Xcode project-specified values AND append your own.  Documentation for each of the build settings including those that you located via copy-paste can be found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html

Glad you were able to get it to work -- now you can really make xcodebuild do even more for you without requiring changes of the target Xcode project!