# iOS - 2 projects in a workspace and referencing the same files - how to determine which project I am in?

Tags: ios, workspace

I currently have 2 projects in a workspace. The files are being referenced from Project A to Project B. My question is what is the cleanest way to determine which project I am in. For instance, I want to use ViewController1 (VC1) for both apps.

Thinking of this with a generic boolean. If I am in project A show this, else show this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do it with command line preprocessor definitions. If you can define _PROJECT_A_ on one, and _PROJECT_B_ on the other, you could do something like:

```
#if defined(_PROJECT_A_)
    // do project A things
    static const BOOL ProjectBMode = NO;
#elif defined(_PROJECT_B_)
    // do project B things
    static const BOOL ProjectBMode = YES;
#endif
```

Or use other `#define`s instead of a `BOOL`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708831/setting-a-define-from-the-command-line-in-xcode-4-6).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this can happen ever and haven't heard of it till now..