# Handling command-line options with the preprocessor in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'd like to set the value of a variable in my Xcode project based on a command-line argument passed into `xcodebuild`.

For instance, I'd like to run `xcodebuild -project MyProj.xcodeproj -alltargets -configuration Debug ENV=2` and have it set a string named "rootUrl" in my code.

I'm expecting something similar to the following in my code:

```
#if (ENV == 2)
static NSString * const rootUrl = @"staging.url.com";
#elif (ENV == 1)
static NSString * const rootUrl = @"dev.url.com";
#else
static NSString * const rootUrl = @"prod.url.com";
#endif
```

But no matter the value of `ENV` I pass into `xcodebuild`, `rootUrl` always gets set to "staging.url.com".

I also have `ENV=$(ENV)` set in my Preprocessor Macros under Build Settings.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `ENV=2` with `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS="ENV=2"` on your command line.  I don't think you need to set the 'Preprocessor Macros' in the Build Settings as it will be overridden anyway.

See [xcodebuild - how to define preprocessor macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708380/xcodebuild-how-to-define-preprocessor-macro) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember it right it is the -D flag you want.. that specifies Preprocessor macros.. so `-DENV=2`